# matlab query in order to see how used the app is

Tags: matlab

I have a MySQL table with over 6 million records, each with a epoch timestamp. I need to plot all the timestamps across time of day. In other words, I need to see how many timestamps are between 7am and 8am, 8am to 9am, etc - for all 24 hour blocks in day. I do not need them plotted by day of the week or month, just time in the day. Each timestamp is in UTC.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use MySQL's [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function to get date strings from the database, and dump the results into a file, which you can subsequently read into MATLAB. Next, one of the ways to extract the time of day of each record is to use MATLAB's [`datevec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html) function, to get each component of the date string seperately:

```
datevec('2007-11-30 10:30:19')

ans =

    2007          11          30          10          30          19
```

For instance, if you read in the data as one long vector with date strings, you could apply `datevec` to this vector, and subsequently grab the 'hour column' of the resulting matrix. Then, you can make a histogram of the counts using the [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html) or [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html) functions, depending on whether you want to specify bin centers or bin edges. If you have an hour column `H`, something like `hist(H, 0:23)` should work. The `histc` function might be a bit more natural for the nature of your data, but is slightly more involved; check the documentation.